# How to read tiff images with lua torch

Tags: lua, tiff, torch

I'm working with tiff images, I am using torch to train a neural network and I need to load the tiff images , there are some library in lua  that can read images tiff???

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the [Torch OpenCV bindings](https://github.com/VisionLabs/torch-opencv) (see this [blog post](http://torch.ch/blog/2016/06/01/deep-fun-with-opencv.html) for more details):

```
local cv = require 'cv'
require 'cv.imgcodecs'

local img = cv.imread{'myimage.tiff', cv.IMREAD_COLOR}
-- note that the layout is HxWxD
-- you can do a permute(3,1,2) to work with DxHxW
```

Another possibility is to use the [graphicsmagick binding](https://github.com/clementfarabet/graphicsmagick):

```
local gm = require 'graphicsmagick'

local img = gm.Image('myimage.tiff'):toTensor('byte', 'RGB', 'DHW')
```